# Cannot find .NET SDK 6.0 on Rocky Linux 8

Tags: .net, dnf

I have to build my .NET project on Rocky Linux 8 machine, but I cannot find `dotnet-sdk-6.0` package from package manager. It seems that recent .NET version is 5. How can I find .NET 6 on Rocky Linux 8?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this [article](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-net-core-on-rocky-linux-almalinux-8/), which installs `dotnet-sdk-6.0` on Rocky Linux 8 manually.